# $_REQUEST array empty on IE11 (windows 8 version 11.0.9600.17937) from xmlHttpRequest, works on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, get, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

I have looked thoroughly on google and stack overflow's history but nothing has fixed my issue.

I have a login feature to my website application which works on Firefox and Chrome with no problem. It also works on IE for every version but one specific version: 11.0.9600.17937 which is for windows 8. My customers are the one who have notified me of this because I have windows 7 and there is no problem on my version of IE11 so I cannot test against the actual issue without asking them to try.

From what I have debugged it appears that my variables are not being passed to the login page via xmlhttprequest because it is not passing my validations to test if the variables are passed in. Once again the validations pass in Firefox and Chrome.

Here is my xmlhttprequest in Javascript:

```
function sendUser(form)
{
    var busloginID=document.forms[0].busloginID.value;
    var buspassword=document.forms[0].buspassword.value;
    var userData = [busloginID, buspassword, 'BUS'];

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else 
    { 
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
        {
            document.getElementById("login").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            if(document.getElementById("loginSuccess"))
            {
                form.submit();
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","login.php?userData="+userData,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And here is the code receiving the xmlhttprequest on login.php:

```php
$data = $_REQUEST['userData'];
$userDataArray = explode(",", $data);
$loginID=$userDataArray[0];
$password=$userDataArray[1];
$originFlag=$userDataArray[2];
```

These variables are not getting passed on this version of IE11, only this specific version.

Any suggestions are appreciated, I feel like I have tried everything.

Thanks

Jake

Comment: To clarify: when the xmlhttprequest comes back it is a valid response. It just doesn't pass my if statement (below) because there were no variables to do the action with on the login.php page:   
  if(document.getElementById("loginSuccess"))

  {

    form.submit();

  }

Comment: It's possible that the issue is not with Internet Explorer itself, but with their specific security settings. Try to replicate the issue in something like [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/) to see if you can get the same error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion samlev. Unfortunately the version of IE11 on BrowserStack is 11.0.9600.16663 not 11.0.9600.17937 so the fact that the login works on BrowserStack in inconclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I substituted $_GET for $_REQUEST when requesting the variables on login.php and the user having the problem stopped experiencing issues. Not sure why that would fix it so it was either the substitution or user error by the client.